# Missed to add the name of co-author

Tags: conference, paper-submission, professorship, ieee

I submitted a conference paper to an IEEE conference via edas system. **I included the details of  co-author in the uploaded document but missed to add in the system**. I noticed it when I received the acceptance notification. When i read the Commsoc policies, it says "it is not possible to add further co-author to a an submitted document". Is this means, I cannot add the co-author name? What will be worst case?

Thank you

Comment: I would contact the organizers and explain the situation. The submission process is different from publishing process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Contact with the ***IEEE conference*** mail and the ***edas system*** as soon as possible.

- The edas mail is: **help@edas.info**
- The IEEE conference you should search in its website. At ***contact*** section probably.

If there's an incongruence between the document and the system they would detect it, but there's no guarantee. So, notify them there was an erratum before the publication is done.

Despite it could have author's incongruence, the document might be published with or without the forgotten author in the systems.

- In the best case, it will be accepted, added the author at the systems and published the documennt including the author.
- In the worst case your document will be rejected.

Answer (score 3):

The worst case is that you are accused by someone of plagiarism. And that is pretty bad. But you don't ask for solutions, though user Younes provides one in a comment.

Contact the organizers, explaining the situation, apologizing and asking for a correction. The organizers, if they have any experience, will have dealt with submission problems in the past and so expect them to happen.

However, if I read it correctly, the paper itself contains the correct author information in its header. The effect, then, of not having entered the co-author into the system is just some confusion on the part of readers who notice it. Conference advertising and such may include less than complete information for example. So, it may be that the "worst case" is an inconsistency in what appears in conference documentation and in the paper itself.

If the paper is correct there will be less of an impact, except for people searching for papers by your co-author and not finding this one since the conference docs are incorrect. If the organizers understand this, they should have an incentive to make it right.